# Understanding the automated mounting of USB Thumbdrive and doing it myself

Tags: ubuntu, mount, usb-drive

I can break this down into two subcomponents:

1. Why/how does this automated mounting procedure create (and destroy) it's own mounting point?
2. Why do I have to manually create my own mount point when doing it myself (or how can I jump on the automated way of doing it)?

I am not clear on the exact process that is going on when I insert a USB key into the system. I see there is a lot going on...

for example, inserting an old USB2 1GB stick:

```
[76187.152010] usb 3-6: new high-speed USB device number 18 using ehci-pci
[76187.285314] usb 3-6: New USB device found, idVendor=1221, idProduct=3234
[76187.285317] usb 3-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[76187.285319] usb 3-6: Product: Flash Disk
[76187.285321] usb 3-6: Manufacturer: USB2.0
[76187.285323] usb 3-6: SerialNumber: 100000000000099E
[76187.285627] usb-storage 3-6:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[76187.285704] scsi host27: usb-storage 3-6:1.0
[76188.285460] scsi 27:0:0:0: Direct-Access     USB2.0   Flash Disk       2.60 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[76188.285731] sd 27:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg11 type 0
[76188.286201] sd 27:0:0:0: [sdk] 2048000 512-byte logical blocks: (1.04 GB/1000 MiB)
[76188.291250] sd 27:0:0:0: [sdk] Write Protect is off
[76188.291255] sd 27:0:0:0: [sdk] Mode Sense: 0b 00 00 08
[76188.292333] sd 27:0:0:0: [sdk] No Caching mode page found
[76188.292337] sd 27:0:0:0: [sdk] Assuming drive cache: write through
[76188.296951]  sdk: sdk1
[76188.300321] sd 27:0:0:0: [sdk] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

and that it get's mounted thusly:

```
/dev/sdk1 on /media/madivad/5859-77E7 type vfat (rw,nosuid,nodev,uid=1000,gid=1000,shortname=mixed,dmask=0077,utf8=1,showexec,flush,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Is it something in the automount process that creates (and later destroys) a directory for the mounting process?

Am I able to identify something on the `mount` command line to create this directly as part of the process and later remove it on `umount`?

Is this something that you would normally automate into a script to remember to first create and `mount` something and then later `umount` it and remove the directory?

I suppose a part of the process that annoys me is that I end up leaving directories that I forget to remove, especially when I'm testing things.

I would like that (for example) when I mount something:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdk1 /mnt/usbkey1g
```

that if the mount point is already created and/or in use that I get a warning, but more importantly, if it's NOT there, then create it on the fly. Likewise, have it removed when I `umount` the key.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed in both Desktop and Server flavours.

I have asked the question here as opposed to AU primarily because I am asking this independent of the actual OS and with reference to Linux generally but as it applies to me. Feel free to have this migrated to AU if it is more appropriate there.

Cheers.

Comment: Try creating a label on the USB stick then look for that label in the standard place fir mounting USB devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, what happens on Ubuntu is that `udisksctl` is called by udev rules , which then mount the devide to media as user into `/media/$USER/diskname` folder.

For all practical purposes it sufficient that you manually do
    udisksctl mount -b /dev/sdb1

Remember to replace your device with actual name

Since in your question you also asked for cross-distro solution, your best solution is the `mount` command, however, bellow is a script where I've basically emulated `udisksctl` command. It will create the directory where it's mounted on the fly and should work on any distro, so long as there are `blkid`, `mount`, and `awk` commands available.

Save the source code in `mountStuff.sh` , make it executable with `chmod +x /path/to/mountStuff.sh`. To avoid constantly running script from full path, it is advisable to have it stored in a directory that is part of your `$PATH` variable

Run as so:

```
skolodya@ubuntu:$ sudo ./mountStuff.sh /dev/sdb5                               
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
Mounted /dev/sdb5 at /media/xieerqi/0ca7543a-5463-4a07-8bbe-233a7b0bd625
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: January 23, 2016
# Script Description: Helper script that
# emulates behavior of udisksctl; reads blkid
# and creates a directory where to mount, based
# on disk label or uuid
#
#
# Copyright Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy 2016
#
# Permission to use, copy, modify, and distribute this software is hereby granted 
# without fee, provided that  the copyright notice above and this permission statement
# appear in all copies.
# 
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR 
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, 
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.  IN NO EVENT SHALL 
# THE AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER 
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING 
# FROM, OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER 
# DEALINGS IN THE SOFTWARE.
if [ "$(id -u)" -ne 0  ];then
   printf ">>> ERR:Must be root"
   exit 1 
fi

if [ -z "$1"  ]; then
     printf ">>> ERR: Must have a parameter, e.g. /dev/sdb1"
     exit 1
fi

if [ "${1%/*}" != "/dev"   ];then
   printf ">>> ERR: Wrong parameter; Must be a device file"
   exit 1
fi

# split output of blkid into array;
# Element 0 is device, element 1 is LABEL or UUID, element 2 is filesystem 
  ARRAY=($( blkid | awk -v DEV="$1"  '$0~DEV{ gsub(/\"/,"");gsub(/\=/," "); print $1,$3,$NF  }'  ))
# the username who ran script as sudo given in $SUDO_USER
if [ ! -d "/media/$SUDO_USER/${ARRAY[1]}" ];
then
  mkdir "/media/$SUDO_USER/${ARRAY[1]}"
fi

mount -t "${ARRAY[2]}" -o rw,user "$1" "/media/$SUDO_USER/${ARRAY[1]}"

if [ "$?" -eq  "0"  ]; then
   printf "Mounted %s at %s" "$1" "/media/$SUDO_USER/${ARRAY[1]}"
fi

skolodya@ubuntu:$ sudo ./mountStuff.sh /dev/sdb5                               
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
Mounted /dev/sdb5 at /media/xieerqi/0ca7543a-5463-4a07-8bbe-233a7b0bd625
```

Comment: excellent, can't wait to read what else you add... But that is exactly what I'm after, thanks! Does it make any different to use `udisksctl unmount -b /dev/sdXn` vs `umount /media/name/drive`. I note that both work as I expect (both remove folder on unmounting), just want to make sure I'm not subverting anything in the `umount`

Comment: @MAdivad to answer your question , there is no difference essentially ; it's just differs by how you refer to it. `umount` example you gave uses path to mount point. The `udisksctl` with `-b` flag that i prefer uses block device from `/dev/` folder. You could use `--object-path` to do the same thing as with `umount`. Check out the `man udiskstcl` for more options.